# SQL query to get the value from score

Tags: sql, database

I have a table like this:

[image]

I need a SQL query to get the value if I have a `2.3` score. So it means the result 2.3 should be between `2.0`/`2.5`/`2.3` and value should be `90`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
select value
from your_table
where 2.3 >= score
order by score
limit 1
```

Depending on your DB engine you need to change the `limit 1` part. To get only the first record DB engines have different methods.

Comment: Are you sure that's what he wants? Why did he include `2.5` in his post?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I think OP did not really think about it or did not describe it well

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select value
from tbl_in_between
where 2.3 between score and (score+0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

In **SQL SERVER** you can do it like:

```
DECLARE @Score NUMERIC(2,1)=2.3

SELECT TOP 1
FROM [YourTable]
WHERE Score<=@Score
ORDER BY Score
```

Comment: ORDER BY is missing

Answer (score 0):

You can try...

```
SELECT TOP 1 value
FROM tbl_in_between
WHERE Score <= 2.3
ORDER BY Score
```